# Cannot install socket.io on windows Error: connect EACCESS

Tags: windows, node.js, socket.io

I am new to what I'm doing now (Node.js,socket.io).
I've already installed Node.js and now I'm trying to install socket.io but I am having this EACCESS error. Thank you for the help!

I'm using Windows 7 x64
I ran cmd with privileges.
and then

```
npm install socket.io
```

Here is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'socket.io' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.14
3 info using node@v0.10.22
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'socket.io', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="socket.io" args=["socket.io",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'socket.io',
7 verbose parsed url   path: 'socket.io',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'socket.io' }
8 silly lockFile 71475bfd-socket-io socket.io
9 verbose lock socket.io C:\Users\Bobby\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\71475bfd-socket-    io.lock
10 silly lockFile 71475bfd-socket-io socket.io
11 silly lockFile 71475bfd-socket-io socket.io
12 verbose addNamed [ 'socket.io', '' ]
13 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
14 silly lockFile c03de861-socket-io socket.io@
15 verbose lock socket.io@ C:\Users\Bobby\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\c03de861-socket-    io.lock
16 silly addNameRange { name: 'socket.io', range: '*', hasData: false }
17 verbose url raw socket.io
18 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './socket.io' ]
19 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
20 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 09:33:49
21 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EACCES
23 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 09:34:00
24 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EACCES
26 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 09:35:00
27 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
28 silly lockFile c03de861-socket-io socket.io@
29 silly lockFile c03de861-socket-io socket.io@
30 error Error: connect EACCES
30 error     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
30 error     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
30 error  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'connect'     }
31 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
32 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
33 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io"
34 error cwd C:\node
35 error node -v v0.10.22
36 error npm -v 1.3.14
37 error syscall connect
38 error code EACCES
39 error errno EACCES
40 error stack Error: connect EACCES
40 error stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
40 error stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You see this? `31 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Comment: Yes, I do. Isn't running cmd with admin privileges enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EACCES means socket.io can't access a port. It might be because you don't have the privileges or the port is already used by another application. You should run this command as an administrator and/or close any process using the port socket.io is trying to access to.

I think it's:

```
runas /noprofile /root:Administrator npm install socket.io
```

Comment: I had to change root to users to get this command to actually run, but this still didn't work for me.